# Change value of array elements X amount of times without starting the array all over

Tags: java

I am trying to change the number of an array 2 times and only 2 times within a [5][4] array.

So say I want to change just the first 2 elements that = 0 to =1, then exit the loop. so element [0] = 1, [1] = 1, then [2] = 0, [3] = 0. Then I want to add change elements [2] and [3] to 1, but leaving elements [0] and [1] = 1. (This is just an example with a 1dimensional array).

This would work for only 5 rows and 2 columns, but how can I do this in a loop? For example if I had a [30][6] array, obviously this would not be efficient. I have tried figuring this out with a for loop, but I just cannot come up with a working way.

```
int numPassengers = 2;
int count = 0;

while (count < numPassengers){

        if(array[0][1] == 0){
            array[0][1] = 1;
            count++;
        }
        else if(array[1][1] == 0){
            array[1][1] = 1;
            count++;
        }
        else if(array[2][1] == 0){
            array[2][1] = 1;
            count++;
        }
        else if(array[3][1] == 0){
            array[3][1] = 1;
            count++;
        }
        else if(array[4][1] == 0){
            array[4][1] = 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Changed the code a little.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ROW; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= 2 ; j++){

            if( array[i][j] == 0){

                if(count < numPassengers){
                    array[i][j]++;
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to find the two first elements in an 2-dimensional array that are 0, and change them to 1.

It's quite simple, you build two nested for loops that browse through the elements one by one:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++) {
        int currentValue = array[i][j];
        // stuff
    }
}
```

(using `length` property of arrays helps to make your code generic)

Then you compare every time `currentValue` with 0. If the comparison is true, then change the element to 1.

```
        if (currentValue == 0) {
            array[i][j] = 1;
        }
```

But you have to stop as soon as you have modified two elements. For that you have to use a variable like `count` in your code.

```
        if (currentValue == 0) {
            array[i][j] = 1;
            count ++;
        }
```

When count is equal to `numPassengers`, you have to go out of your TWO loops. You can do it using a labeled `break` statement (a simple break would only get you out of the inner loop):

before the first `for`:

```
outerloop:
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
```

and then after `count++`:

```
            count ++;
            if (count == numPassengers) {
                break outerloop;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me out a lot. I changed the code a bit so I didn't have to use break.